# Angular 7 window resize event not running in service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following service with a ReplaySubject variable that I would like to use in components, and my understanding is that it should work, but the WindowResize event isn't firing at all.

```
import { Injectable, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
  export class WindowResizeService {

    windowWidth;

    constructor() {
      console.log("Window resize service active");
      this.windowWidth = new ReplaySubject(1);
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
      console.log("Width: " + event.target.innerWidth);
      this.windowWidth.next(event.target.innerWidth);
    } 
}
```

In the component, I've subscribed in the following way:

```
import { WindowResizeService } from './window-resize-service';

constructor(private windowResize: WindowResizeService) implements OnInit {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.windowResize.windowWidth.subscribe(
        (value) => { console.log(value) }
    );
}
```

So I get the `Window resize service active` event, but the `console.log` in the Service or the Component aren't being ran. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `HostListener` is what it says it is. It listens for events on the host component. Just the convenience that you can use the extra `window`, `document` or `body` binding for a global listener, does not make the HostListener work inside a service.

For this you either have to use the `Renderer`, the simple `window.addEventListener` or the rxjs `fromEvent(window)`.

Another way to do it, is to add the `@HostListener()` to the AppComponent (and only there), and let it emit the service observable from there.

Comment: Cheers, that's what I figured a bit after I asked  and was about to add it as `window.addEventListener`, however having it in AppComponent sounds cleaner. Will mark your answer as correct in 5 mins when the timer is up.